# why mongo db serverStatus connections current is not equals netstat count

Tags: mongodb

As the question say

I logined the mongos, and did an db.serverStatus().connections, it shown below

```
mongos> db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 110, "available" : 19890 }
```

but, when I use

```
$ sudo netstat -nap | grep mongos -c
  1369
```

as you see, its count is 1387

and also

```
$ sudo netstat -nap | grep mongos | grep ESTABLISHED -c
1366
```

my question is: why these two count are not the same (or even similar)???

Please show me the way, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

`netstat` might be counting connections that are stuck in a closing state, timing out, etc.

What does `netstat -nap | grep mongos | grep ESTABLISHED` show?

Comment: How many secondaries and MongoSes do you have? Are you using MMS or Munin to monitor?

Comment: totally 12 nodes, it is that hits 1366 / 12 ??

Comment: What is the breakdown of the nodes? Out of the 12, how many are secondaries, primaries, config servers, mongoses, etc?